# Using mgo for nested document fields

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am using Golang with mgo driver for mongodb.

According to example at http://labix.org/mgo everything works great. But I can not find any documentation how mgo supports "dot notation" to be able to set and remove nested fields. So, how can I accesss nested fields?

Another question  is related to go Lang name convention. When I fill my structure with s.FindId(...).One(&doc) can doc have fields with lower case names like "timer" instead of "Timer"?

Do mgo have possibility to get not structured document from mongo and just return map[string]string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [mgo/bson docs](http://go.pkgdoc.org/launchpad.net/mgo/v2/bson#Marshal) on how to use lower case fields.

Comment: Thanks! OK, so by default all names translates to lower case. For custom mapping we can specify just bson field name.
`type timer struct {
 Code     string
 Duration int64
 StartAt  int64 ``bson:"startAt"``
}`
Also nested fields should be present in code like structure of structure.